# Update order status via AJAX in WooCommerce Order received page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to change the status of my woocommerce orders from processing to completed when a client clicks a button on the thank you page via AJAX.

My code is as follows:

```js
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: ajax_url,
    data: {action: 'redeem_complete'},
    success: function(response){
        alert("Order data successfully fetched.");                      
    }
});
```

and the php in my functions.php

```php
add_action( 'wp_ajax_redeem_complete', 'fairbooks_redeem_complete');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_redeem_complete', 'fairbooks_redeem_complete');

function fairbooks_redeem_complete($order_id){
        
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); 
    $order->update_status( 'completed' );
    echo 'test';
    die();
}
```

I know the ajax works without the `$order->update_status( 'completed' );` statement, but with it I get a 500 internal server error. I also know that If I don't use ajax and hook into the thank you page it changes the status without a problem. What is causing the error or is there perhaps a better way to go about this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You need **to pass the order Id from your javascript code to PHP** as its not defined in your PHP WordPress Ajax receiver function, so it's normal to get an error 500 as `$order` variable is not defined and throw an error when using the method `update_status()`.

The following complete example is based on your code *(and works without errors)*:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'customer_completes_order_thankyou' );
function customer_completes_order_thankyou( $order_id ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
     // print_r($order->get_status()); // Uncomment for testing
    ?>
    <div><button class="button alt complete-status"><?php _e("Complete your order"); ?></button><br><br>
    <span class="response" style="color:green;"></span></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
        if (typeof woocommerce_params === 'undefined')
            return false;

        $('button.complete-status').click( function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: woocommerce_params.ajax_url,
                data: {
                    'action': 'redeem_complete',
                    'order_id': <?php echo $order_id; ?>, // Here we send the order Id
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    $('.response').text("Order data successfully fetched.");
                    console.log("Order data successfully fetched.");
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_redeem_complete', 'fairbooks_redeem_complete');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_redeem_complete', 'fairbooks_redeem_complete');
function fairbooks_redeem_complete(){
    if ( isset($_POST['order_id']) && $_POST['order_id'] > 0 ) {
        $order = wc_get_order($_POST['order_id']);
        $order->update_status('completed');
        die();
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.