# Check if checkbox is checked without clicking it

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a input checkbox that has been modified to be buttons one for `approve` one for `reject` when approved is selected it checks the box etc. Once selected a third button `save` submits. If I check the box without using the buttons my script works but then I loose other functionality already associated with the buttons.

The code below is based on [Update order status via AJAX in WooCommerce Order received page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64164349/update-order-status-via-ajax-in-woocommerce-order-received-page/64165105#64165105)

How can I listen and **detect if the checkbox has been selected** even it was **checked by selecting the button** and not the actual checkbox.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".wcfa-save-button").click(function() {
                if ($("input[type=checkbox]").is(":checked").length > 0) {

            alert("Check box is Checked");


            $('button.wcfa-save-button').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: "woocommerce_params.ajax_url",
                    data: {
                        'action': 'redeem_complete',
                        'order_id': orerId, // Here we send the order Id
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        $('.response').text("Order data successfully fetched.");
                        console.log("Order data successfully fetched.");
                    }
                });
            });

        } else {
            alert("Check box is Unchecked");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="wcfa-attachment" class="wcfa-hidden" id="wcfa-approved-result" data-id="attachmentID">

<button id="wcfa-approve-button-ID" class="button wcfa-approve-button" data-approval="approved" data-id="attachmentID">Approve</a>
<button id="wcfa-reject-button-attachmentID" class="button wcfa-reject-button" data-approval="rejected" data-id="attachmentID">Reject</a>
<button class="button wcfa-save-button wcfa-disable-during-transition" data-id="attachmentID">Save</button>
```

[image]

**Update** Was unable to target the checkbox, ended up checking if the `approve` button `.hasClass` of `wcfa-approve-active-button` then sending the submit

```
  $('button.wcfa-save-button').click( function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

    if ( $('.wcfa-approve-button').hasClass('wcfa-approve-active-button')) {
                    alert("Check box in Checked"); 
                    console.log("Checkbox is Checked");
```

Comment: Do not bind events inside of events

Comment: Can you minimise the code in your question? The PHP parts are entirely irrelevant, strip it down to only enough code to reproduce the problem (the Ajax functionality, for instance, is relevant to your production code but serves only to complicate your question and makes it more tedious to read, especially so given that you have PHP interspersed in there as well). Please: "*[mcve]*", that way we don't have to trim things down for you (many times over in each/every answer).

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. There are several missing `</button>`  - don't wrap links in buttons or buttons in links

Comment: Your code however works as expected even with the invalid HTML

Comment: So bind a click to the element or form submission. Inside of that methodm check the state of the checkbox. Basic form validation.

Comment: The form is submitted via AJAX there is no refresh of the page

Comment: I'm getting the checkbox is checked alert even when using the button but then the Ajax post portion does not have any effect. If I physically check the box then the Ajax post works. I don't understand why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this is related to WordPress (WooCommerce) you need to start by `jQuery` first… Then the following will detect if your checkbox is checked or not *(on start and on change)*…

Here is the revisited code:

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
    // On start
    if ( $('input[name="wcfa-attachment"]').is(":checked") ) {
        console.log("Start: Checkbox is Checked");
    } else {
        console.log("Start: Checkbox NOT Checked");
    }
    
    // On change
    $('input[name="wcfa-attachment"]').on('change', function(){

        if ( $(this).is(":checked") ) {
            console.log("Checkbox is Checked");

            $('button.wcfa-save-button').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                if (typeof woocommerce_params === 'undefined')
                    return false;
                    
                var orderId = 858; // Set an existing order ID or a dynamic variable with php

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: "woocommerce_params.ajax_url",
                    data: {
                        'action': 'redeem_complete',
                        'order_id': orderId, // Here we send the order Id
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        $('.response').text("Order data successfully fetched.");
                        console.log("Order data successfully fetched.");
                    }
                });
            });

        } else {
            console.log("Checkbox NOT Checked");
        }
    });
});
</script>
<input type="checkbox" name="wcfa-attachment" class="wcfa-hidden" id="wcfa-approved-result" data-id="attachmentID" />
<button id="wcfa-approve-button-ID" class="button wcfa-approve-button" data-approval="approved" data-id="attachmentID">Approve</button>
<button id="wcfa-reject-button-attachmentID" class="button wcfa-reject-button" data-approval="rejected" data-id="attachmentID">Reject</button>
<button class="button wcfa-save-button wcfa-disable-during-transition" data-id="attachmentID">Save</button>
```

Tested and works.

Comment: Thank you this must be close, I've got it setup and logging in console when the checkbox is actually clicked on, but the same problem persists, if the button is used to check off the checkbox the console doesn't log that the checkbox is checked and subsequently the order status fails to change to pending. It does successfully change to pending if the actual checkbox is used.

Comment: @user2059376 Could you provide the complete code in your question, as it isn't testable actually, maybe with some more details…

Comment: I've got it sorted, if the approve button `.hasClass` on click of submit, instead of targeting the checkbox itself. 
`$('button.wcfa-save-button').click( function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
        if ( $('.wcfa-approve-button').hasClass('wcfa-approve-active-button')) {
                        alert("Check box in Checked"); 
                        console.log("Checkbox is Checked");`

Answer (score 1):

You cab check if the checkbox is checked or not using "length", you can do something like below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function checkIfChecked(){
        if ($("input[type=checkbox]").is(":checked").length > 0) {
            alert("Check box is Checked");


            $('button.wcfa-save-button').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: "woocommerce_params.ajax_url",
                    data: {
                        'action': 'redeem_complete',
                        'order_id': orerId, // Here we send the order Id
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        $('.response').text("Order data successfully fetched.");
                        console.log("Order data successfully fetched.");
                    }
                });
            });

        } else {
            alert("Check box is Unchecked");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

a) one set of click listener for checkbox, approve & reject button

b) second click listener for save which checks checkbox state and fires ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $("input[type=checkbox], .wcfa-approve-button, .wcfa-reject-button").click(function(){
    const identifier = $(this).attr('data-identifier');

    switch (identifier) {
      case 'btn-approve': 
        alert('Approve Clicked');
        $("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked",true); 
        break;
      case 'btn-reject': 
        alert('Reject Clicked');
        $("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked",false); break;
      case 'checkbox': 
        alert('Checkbox Clicked');
        let isChecked = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length > 0;
        $("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", isChecked); 
        break;
    }
  });

  $("button.wcfa-save-button").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Save Clicked');

    if ($("input[type=checkbox]").is(":checked")) {
      alert("Check box is Checked");

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "woocommerce_params.ajax_url",
        data: {
          action: "redeem_complete",
          order_id: 'orerId' // Here we send the order Id
        },
        success: function(response) {
          $(".response").text("Order data successfully fetched.");
          console.log("Order data successfully fetched.");
        }
      });
    } else {
      alert("Check box is Unchecked");
    }
  });
});
```

Stackblitz link - https://stackblitz.com/edit/jquery-1mn3mr?file=index.html